# Placing an oracle query within a subquery within the select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have a query that looks up the student number and race of a student. The query combines duplicate rows when a student would have more than one ethnicity. Here is the query:

```
select 
   Student_number,
       CASE WHEN (COUNT(DISTINCT sr.raced) > 1) THEN 'Two or more races'
            ELSE MAX(sr.racecd)
       END
   end as races 
from student
left join studentrace SR....
```

My issues arises when I am trying to place this within an xml file for a plugin. The system will not accept aggregation/filters unless it is within a subquery. Is it possible to place this query within a subquery in the select statement? Thank your for any help on this issue.
BTW I don't need the student number within a subquery only the races field.

Comment: Can you just wrap the whole thing in a SELECT * FROM ([current query])  ? If your plugin limits you too severely, you can always just create a view and query the view straight up (select * from view)

Comment: Thats a good idea. Would I have to set parenthesis from the select all the way down to the Group By statement?

Comment: yes... wrap the entire SQL in parentheses and select from it

Comment: Thanks. The subquery worked, but the system still won't accept it. I will have to find another route to get the data in. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get result data without a join.

```
Select racecd 
From studentrace
Where ...
Group By racecd
--, studentid
Having Count(1) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not beeeing sure about the context and data, just guessing, but maybe this code could help you solve your problem:

```sql
SELECT      s.STUDENT_NUMBER,
            CASE  WHEN sr.CNT_RACED > 1 THEN 'Two or more races'
                  WHEN sr.CNT_RACED Is Null THEN 'No matching data in table studentrace'
            ELSE  sr.MAX_RACECD
            END "RACES"
FROM        student s
LEFT JOIN   ( Select STUDENT_NUMBER, CNT_RACED, MAX_RACECD 
              From ( Select    STUDENT_NUMBER, Count(DISTINCT RACED) "CNT_RACED", Max(RACE_CD) "MAX_RACECD"
                     From      studentrace 
                     Group By  STUDENT_NUMBER  ) "RACES"
            ) sr ON(sr.STUDENT_NUMBER = s.STUDENT_NUMBER)
```

With some simple imaginary sample data:

```sql
WITH
    student AS
        (
            Select 1 "STUDENT_NUMBER", 'Jack' "STUDENT_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "STUDENT_NUMBER", 'Jane' "STUDENT_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "STUDENT_NUMBER", 'Mick' "STUDENT_NAME" From Dual 
        ),
    studentrace AS
        (
            Select 1 "STUDENT_NUMBER", 'RACE_A' "RACED", 'RACECD_X' "RACE_CD" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "STUDENT_NUMBER", 'RACE_B' "RACED", 'RACECD_Y' "RACE_CD" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "STUDENT_NUMBER", 'RACE_B' "RACED", 'RACECD_W' "RACE_CD" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "STUDENT_NUMBER", 'RACE_C' "RACED", 'RACECD_Y' "RACE_CD" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "STUDENT_NUMBER", 'RACE_A' "RACED", 'RACECD_Z' "RACE_CD" From Dual 
        )
```

... it would result as:

```sql
STUDENT_NUMBER RACES                               
-------------- -------------------------------------
             1 Two or more races                     
             2 RACECD_W                              
             3 Two or more races
```

The table student is left  joined to the query that gets the aggregated values from a subquery - if that is what you need. This could be done in a way that each aggregated value (Count() and Max()) are fetched from it's own separate subquery too.